# Cannot connect docker Spring-Boot app with mysql container and flyway in docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot, flyway

I have a little spring-boot service with a connection to mysql. The application setup works fine when I run the app with maven and a docker container for mysql.

Now I want to run the app with docker too, so I use docker-compose to bootstrap mysql and my service as containers.

But I doesn't work, my service can't connect to mysql, the following exception occurs:

```
accountservice_1 | 2015-11-18 08:55:11.626 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
accountservice_1 | com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
accountservice_1 | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:983) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:339) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2252) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2285) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2084) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50) [flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1385) [flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) [flyway-core-3.2.1.jar!/:na]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.3.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
accountservice_1 |  at net.twentyfourseven.account.AccountServiceApplication.main(AccountServiceApplication.java:44) [account-service.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [account-service.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
accountservice_1 |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:214) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
accountservice_1 |  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:298) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar!/:5.1.37]
```

It seems that there is a problem with the Flyway db migration...

Now, when my service container exited and I exit docker-compose with CTRL-C and restart with docker-compose up, everything is fine, my servive and mysql starts and the flyway migration happens as expected.

Does anyone has an idea? It' ok for me, because I know everything will be fine on second startup, but I really don't why this error occurs and that is really annoying...

Here's my config, abbreviated:

```
flyway:
    enabled: true

spring.datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbaccounts
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
mysqlaccounts:
  image: mysql:5.6
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: dbaccounts

accountservice:
  image: account-service
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  links:
    - mysqlaccounts
  environment:
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqlaccounts:3306/dbaccounts
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
    - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
```

When I disable flyway from the beginning, everything is fine too...

Thanks in advance for ANY ideas and suggestions..;)

P.S: I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, Java8, spring-boot 1.3.RELEASE and Docker 1.9.0 and docker-compose version: 1.5.1 .

Comment: I am having the same issue, where you able to fix this? Or is it a bug in the latest compose?

Comment: Sorry, found no solution yet...

Comment: @MarkusLamm Could you post the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the host in `datasource url` to the ip of `docker-machine`. It will look like:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100/dbaccounts
```